# SSRS - Showing data's each character in box

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

From my stored procedure, I'm returning the data of pin code `600100`.

I want to show my data inside the boxes as per the below screen shot.

> [image: Pincode]

I adding 6 textboxes and doing string calculation to put each character in each box.

Is there any other way to achieve this by using Table, Matrix or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an easy way to do this. You might be able to do it if you break up the PIN code into 6 fields in the query and then use a matrix to display it but that would be a lot of work for not much gain. You're still doing a similar thing - the only advantage is if your PIN number has more digits.